# EPPlus chart does not keep relative cell references on row insert

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a sheet with a bar chart like this
[image]

When I insert a row using EPPlus

```
sheet.InsertRow(20, 1);
```

and save the sheet again the result is
[image]

I would expect the chart to respond the same as if I where to have added it in excel and still reference the last row.

This is an over simplified example of my problem, but is there another way of making the chart be relative to the editing I am doing (without doing manual adjustments)?